Fixing SCSS to add a 'responsive' and 'scalable' svg behind certain text
I have attempted to create a 'scribble' type effect behind some text, so created two (one is only a longer svg version for longer words) classes that places a svg as a background on text that has the class added to it.
The base code is here;
.asset_circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

  // SVG background
        &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: -webkit-fill-available;
        height: -webkit-fill-available;
        background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/asset_circle-1.svg') no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain; // Ensures the SVG covers the entire circle
        transform: scale(1.5); // Centre the SVG
        z-index: -1; // Places the SVG behind the text
        }   
}

.asset_circle_long {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    
          // SVG background
          &::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: -webkit-fill-available;
            height: -webkit-fill-available;
            background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/Asset-circle-long.svg') no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain; // Ensures the SVG covers the entire circle
            transform: scale(1.5); // Centre the SVG
            z-index: -1; // Places the SVG behind the text
          }
}

While we have gotten this to display on MAC and Android, there seems to be placement issues on iPhones (doesn't matter the browser used).
Tried various ways to alter this to work better for iphone, however any code adjustments to fix the code for iPhone has resulted in the code then failing on Mac and Android.

If you provide a minimal, reproducible example people will be more able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
